# How to get a String from not null values of the columns row wise in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL like below,

[image: Screenshot]

Now I want to get an output like below,

```
id |username |accessLevel
============================ 
6  |deepaku8 |arch[ALL]
7  |kirajama |arch[ALL]- geo[APJ]
8  |asau     |arch[Data Center]- geo[EMEAR_REGION]
```

Is there any way to achieve this result by *SQL query* ?

Comment: Do you want a flexible query that will cope if new columns are added, or it is used on a different table. Or just a basic query to use on that particular table?

Comment: @Kickstart yeah just a basic query to get the result is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the basics for you table (guessing the columns you want)

```
SELECT id,
        username,
        CONCAT_WS(' - ', 
            IF(arch IS NULL OR arch = '', NULL, CONCAT('arch', '[', arch, ']')),
            IF(geo IS NULL OR geo = '', NULL, CONCAT('geo', '[', geo, ']')),
            IF(theater IS NULL OR theater = '', NULL, CONCAT('theater', '[', theater, ']')),
            IF(operation IS NULL OR operation = '', NULL, CONCAT('operation', '[', operation, ']')),
            IF(region IS NULL OR region = '', NULL, CONCAT('region', '[', region, ']')),
            IF(country IS NULL OR country = '', NULL, CONCAT('country', '[', country, ']')),
            IF(technology IS NULL OR technology = '', NULL, CONCAT('technology', '[', technology, ']')),
            IF(subTechnology IS NULL OR subTechnology = '', NULL, CONCAT('subTechnology', '[', subTechnology, ']'))
        ) AS accessLevel
FROM some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You query in SQL using the `SELECT` statement. SQL commands are implemented as SQL command strings. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx) is a good tutorial by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat_ws` to do this.
`concat` returns `null` if any of the values is `null` and `concat_ws` ignores `null` values during concatenation.

```
select id,username,
concat_ws('-',concat('arch','[',if(arch='',null,arch),']'),
              concat('geo','[',if(geo='',null,geo),']'), 
              concat('technology','[',if(technology='',null,technology),']')
           --add more values as required
         )
from tablename
```